# Normative reference for a web application disclosing existing values of integration secrets to users

Tags: defense, owasp

In a web-based SaaS product, one of the configuration pages allows users to set credentials for system-wide integrations with other products. These include usernames, passwords, and API secrets.

The sensitive fields are set as `type="password"`, but when loading the page, any existing values are provided by the server in the `value="..."` attribute on those fields, allowing a user who can view that page to extract values previously configured by a different user.

This feels like poor practice - placeholders should be used instead, with the stored secrets only being updated when a new value is provided by the user - but I'm struggling to find a normative reference I can point the vendor towards.

https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Key_Management_Cheat_Sheet.html#key-compromise-and-recovery makes some mention of not allowing humans to view symmetric or private keys, but that doesn't feel directly on point.

https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/200.html is perhaps a better fit but rather general.

Are there any "don't include existing sensitive values in configuration pages" statements in any of the usual standards?